# Memory leak in cocoa touch with a mutableCopy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to resolve a memory leak but I can't find any solution.

Instruments says that there is a leak in this method:

```
 - (void)refreshData {

 Sn0werSp33dAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[Sn0werSp33dAppDelegate alloc] init];
 NSFetchRequest *coreDataNewsFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

 [coreDataNewsFetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
 self.newsArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:coreDataNewsFetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];//Intruments says that here is the memory leak :(


 [appDelegate release];
 [coreDataNewsFetchRequest release];
 [entity release];
}
```

`newsArray` is declared in my .h as an NSMutableArray and it has a property:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newsArray;`

I've tried many things but at all times, that things weren't working.
I'm running XCode 3.2.5 with iPhone SDK 4.2.1 and Instruments 2.7.

Comment: You should format your code so that it's readable.

Comment: can you please format the code a little? besides, can you say, what instruments says? Remember that mutablecopy does not make a deep copy of an array!

Comment: It just shows me one red stack on one blue. And, Is that code formatting right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do

```
self.newsArray = something;
```

that `something` is retained, because you added `retain` to the `newsArray` property.

But `mutableCopy` also returns an object with a retain count increased by 1. So after the method finishes, your `newsArray` has a retain count one higher than what you really want, which is the  memory leak that was detected.

Solution: Replace the line where you assign `self.newsArray` with

```
self.newsArray = [[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:coreDataNewsFetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds. :-)

Comment: Thanks mrueg, I thought that won't work and so I haven't tried it. Thanks you again :D

Answer (score 3):

`mutableCopy` makes a copy and retains it, so you need to release the copy you've created. Try changing this:

```
self.newsArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:coreDataNewsFetchRequest 
                                                      error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

To this:

```
self.newsArray = [[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:coreDataNewsFetchRequest 
                                                       error:nil] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

---

As an aside, creating a new object of your app delegate class is a little unusual and might not give you the result you expect. Conventionally you instantiate one app delegate (by default this is done for you in MainWindow.xib) and then refer to it throughout your app using:

```
FooAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FooAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: It already gives me the result I want, but i need to release the appDelegate and I don't know where to release It :(